# Cannot use a variable in Rmarkdown file in Bookdown/Hugo

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, bookdown

I have created a simple website using Bookdown. I have a page:

```
---
title: Home
---

# Page title    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

However, instead of *Page title* I wanna show a value coming from my `config.toml` file.

#### What I tried

I want to show the value of a [site variable](https://gohugo.io/variables/site/), defined in `config.toml` file, so I did:

```
---
title: Home
---

# {{ $.Site.Params.author }}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Having my configuration file like this:

```
[params]
    author = "Me myself and I"
    description = "My website"
```

However the value is not resolved. It is my understanding that I need to use a template, however, there is really no way to have a variable inside a content file?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way I found to do this is via [shortcodes](https://gohugo.io/templates/shortcode-templates/):

1. I created a shortcode inside `layouts/shortcodes` like: `myvar.html` and placed there the string I want to emit
2. Referenced the shortcode from the Rmarkdown file

The content file will look like:

```
---
title: Home
---

# {{< myvar >}}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

That worked!

Comment: Or use R to read your config file, then embed an inline R expression.

Comment: @YihuiXie It's an honor to "meet" you sir! Amazing work, I am liking it so much :) Please post it as an answer, you comment I mean, because I will probably go for it and that is a valid approach I will mark here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! I think both approaches should work, and I don't really have a preference. Just use the one that works for you.